# Want to plot dual-y-axis and show the legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a dual-y-axis in ggplot. The primary y-axis is called `Payout (GDD)` in my dataset, while the secondary y-axis is called `yield_loss_ratio_1` in my dataset. I have an issue in the secondary `yield_loss_ratio_1` y-axis where the its counts are similar to the counts of the primary y-axis and not representing actual counts that I want in the secondary axis.

Any ideas and thoughts on how to plot the chart as I require and to show the legend of the plot?

I need to plot some thing similar to the below image.

[image]

And this is the image I got from the ggplot:

[image]

I tried this chunk of code:

```
fig_GDD <- payout_yeild_loss %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = year, y = `Payout (GDD)`), fill = "black") +
  geom_point(aes(x = year, y = yield_loss_ratio_1),
    color = "red",
    size = 3,
    shape = 15
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = yield_loss_ratio_1),
    color = "red",
    size = 1
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Payout (RM/°C)",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.,
      name = "Yield loss ratio (%)"
    ),
    expand = c(0.01, 0)
  ) +
  scale_x_date(
    date_breaks = "2 year",
    date_labels = "%Y",
    expand = c(0.01, 0)
  ) +
  labs(
    x = " "
  ) +
  theme_classic()
```

Here is the dput of my data

```
structure(list(year = structure(c(11323, 11688, 12053, 12418, 
12784, 13149, 13514, 13879, 14245, 14610, 14975, 15340, 15706, 
16071, 16436, 16801), class = "Date"), `seaon 1 (kg/ha)` = c(5215, 
5585, 5690, 5730, 6084, 5982, 5849, 5971, 6189, 6070, 6049, 6312, 
6595, 6478, 6282, 6247), `Season 2 (kg/ha)` = c(4845, 5259, 5220, 
5440, 3936, 5463, 5429, 6120, 5656, 5890, 5147, 5266, 6452, 5161, 
6141, 5344), `Cumulative GDD - S1 (C°)` = c(544, 557, 552, 549, 
568, 547, 557, 549, 580, 567, 562, 565, 557, 576, 564, 563), 
    `Cumulative rainfall - S2 (mm)` = c(81, 96, 26, 71, 490, 
    48, 163, 36, 17, 104, 76, 67, 23, 242, 87, 120), `Payout (GDD)` = c(70, 
    12, 34, 48, 0, 56, 13, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0), `Payout(CR)` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 242, 0, 214, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 242, 0, 42), yield_loss_ratio_1 = c(15, 
    8, 6, 5, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), yeild_loss_ratio_2 = c(12, 
    3, 4, 0, 38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 5, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your legend is that you have set the colors as arguments. If you want to have a legend you have to map on aesthetics and set your color via `scale_xxx_manaual`. The issue with the scale of your secondary axis is that YOU have to do the rescaling of the axis and the data manually. `ggplot2` will not do that for your. In the code below I use `scales::rescale` to first rescale the data to be displayed on the secondary axis and to retransform inside `sec_axis()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

range_yield <- range(payout_yeild_loss$yield_loss_ratio_1)
range_gdd <- range(payout_yeild_loss$`Payout (GDD)`)

payout_yeild_loss$yield_loss_ratio_1 <- scales::rescale(payout_yeild_loss$yield_loss_ratio_1, to = range_gdd)
ggplot(payout_yeild_loss) +
  geom_col(aes(x = year, y = `Payout (GDD)`, fill = "black")) +
  geom_point(aes(x = year, y = yield_loss_ratio_1,  color = "red"),
    size = 3,
    shape = 15
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = yield_loss_ratio_1, color = "red"),
    size = 1
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Payout (RM/°C)",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ scales::rescale(., to = range_yield),
      name = "Yield loss ratio (%)"
    ),
    expand = c(0.01, 0)
  ) +
  scale_x_date(
    date_breaks = "2 year",
    date_labels = "%Y",
    expand = c(0.01, 0)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "black") +
  scale_color_manual(values = "red") +
  labs(
    x = " "
  ) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]